# How can I add items to the data source of a kendo ui grid

Tags: javascript, grid, kendo-ui

I have created a kendo.data.dataSource with success, and I am able to bind it to the KendoUI Grid on my page.

But when I try to `dataSource.insert(0, [a : "b"]);` it removes the data that was there previously.

My example code follows:

```
var tempSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
     data: [{"ID":1,"Name":"Cliente 1","NameID":"1 - Cliente 1"},{"ID":2,"Name":"Cliente 2","NameID":"2 - Cliente 2"}]
});
```

This is how I'm binding to the grid:

```
$("#association-grid").kendoGrid({
height: 99,
columns:
[
    {
        field: "ID",
        title: "ID"
    },
    {
        field: "Name",
        title: "Name"
    },
    {
        field: "NameID",
        title: "NameID"
    }
],

dataSource: tempSource
});
```

This is how I add a new item:

```
tempSource.insert(0, { ID: "John Smith", Name: "Product Description", NameID: "123 1st Street" });
```

If I perform the add before binding the data to the Grid, I lose the first two items that were originally on the dataSource object.

In summary:
I have a pre-created dataSource binded to a Grid. I want to be able to add a new item to the dataSource, and then refresh the Grid so that the new item appears.

Thanks,

VRC

Answer (score 26, accepted):

try this:

```
dataSource.add({ name: "John Smith", description: "Product Description", address: "123 1st Street" });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var grid = $("#itemsGrid").data("kendoGrid");

                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

                        grid.dataSource.insert(data[i]);
                    }
```

> inserting new record to grid datasource